# What's the difference between rememberUpdatedState and using mutableStateOf in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm quite confused with the use case of `rememberUpdatedState`

isn't this essentially the same with using `mutableStateOf` without `remember`? In this case what's the use case of `rememberUpdatedState` if it is updating every time with the new value?

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  var var1 by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
  }
  Column {
    Text(
      text = "Var 1: $var1"
    )
    Button(onClick = {
      var1 += 1
    }) {
      Text("Increment")
    }
    
    TextChild(derivedVar = var1)
  }
}

@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Composable
fun TextChild(derivedVar: Int) {
  var var1 by remember {
    mutableStateOf(derivedVar)
  } // Will NOT update ever
  var var2 = mutableStateOf(derivedVar) // Will always have same value as var3
  var var3 = rememberUpdatedState(newValue = derivedVar) // Will always have same value as var2

  Column {
    Text(
      text = "Derived var here",
      fontSize = 30.sp
    )
    Text(
      text = "Value var1: $var1",
      fontSize = 30.sp
    )
    Text(
      text = "Value var2: ${var2.value}",
      fontSize = 30.sp
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example you are not updating or recomposing `TextChild` via any of the variables inside `TextChild`.

When `TextChild` is recomposed **new** instance of `MutableState` with value `derivedVar` will be assigned to `var2`. `remember` is for storing previous instance. When `var4` is updated inside `TextChild` it recomposes `TextChild` and when new derivedValue is passed block of remember is called and new instance of `MutableState` with `derivedVar` is created or we can say it's reset to `derivedVar`.

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Composable
fun TextChild(derivedVar: Int) {

    var var2 = mutableStateOf(derivedVar) // Will always have same value as var3
    val var3 = rememberUpdatedState(newValue = derivedVar) // Will always have same value as var2
    val var4 = remember(derivedVar) {
        mutableStateOf(derivedVar)
    }

    Column {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                var2.value = var2.value + 1
            }
        ) {
            Text("Var2")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                var4.value = var4.value + 1

            }
        ) {
            Text("Var4")
        }
        Text(
            text = "Derived var here",
            fontSize = 30.sp
        )

        Text(
            text = "Value var2: ${var2.value}",
            fontSize = 30.sp
        )
        Text(
            text = "Value var3: ${var3.value}",
            fontSize = 30.sp
        )
        Text(
            text = "Value var4: ${var4.value}",
            fontSize = 30.sp
        )
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70223293/5457853

In the link you can see that rememberUpdatedState is used for containing last value because it is actually

```
@Composable
fun <T> rememberUpdatedState(newValue: T): State<T> = remember {
    mutableStateOf(newValue)
}.apply { value = newValue }
```

`rememberUpdatedState` is also useful for closures like `DisposabbleEffect` or `LaunchedEffect` which are both remember under the hood, when a closure captures a `State`, also applies to loops(awaitEachGesture) inside `pointerInput`.

If you change TextChild with this Composable

```
@Composable
private fun Calculation(derivedVar: Int) {
    val var1 = remember(derivedVar) {
        mutableStateOf(derivedVar)
    }

    val var2 = rememberUpdatedState(derivedVar)

    println("Inside Recomposition var1: $var1, var2: $var2")

    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        delay(2000)
        println("Inside LaunchedEffect var1: $var1, var2: $var2")
    }
}


 I  Inside Recomposition var1: MutableState(value=0)@186998035, var2: MutableState(value=0)@16161616
 I  Inside Recomposition var1: MutableState(value=1)@182692437, var2: MutableState(value=1)@16161616
 I  Inside Recomposition var1: MutableState(value=2)@266344464, var2: MutableState(value=2)@16161616
 I  Inside LaunchedEffect var1: MutableState(value=0)@186998035, var2: MutableState(value=2)@16161616
```

if you click the button in parent Composable and update `var1` newly assigned `MutableState` never passed into LaunchedEffect in example above, it retains first MutableState instance as can be see in logs. But the MutableState assigned to var1 is already changed 2 times and not the first instance.

Another case of closure retaining previous instance

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73610519/5457853

Answer (score 2):

`rememberUpdatedState` is a function that supports a pattern that is easy to get wrong. The `remember` prefix is used to indicate that `remember` is called implicitly and the `State` suffix indicates that it returns a `State<T>` (which is the type returned by `mutableStateOf<T>()`).

It is literally what it says on the tin:

```
fun <T> rememberUpdatedState(newValue: T): State<T> = remember {
    mutableStateOf(newValue)
}.apply { value = newValue }
```

It is a mutable state that is remembered and updated to the given value.

You should use `rememberUpdatedState` when you want a `State<T>` that is updated by composition for use by something outside of composition, by, for example, a `LaunchedEffect`. You usually don't need it but we found it common enough in building Compose UI and Compose Foundation, and it was often written incorrectly (some of which you cover in your question), we created a function to use instead of having to create this pattern yourself ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not create a mutable state in a Composable without `remember`.

[image: Warning screenshot]

A state without remember will be initialized every time the Composable recomposes.

For example, if you have a counter state to store an `Int` and a `Button` to increase the count by 1 each time the `Button` is clicked. The count will always be initialized to `0` each time the Composable recomposes as the previous value is not `remembered`.

You can try removing the `remember` from this example to understand this better.

```
@Composable
fun RememberCounterSample() {
    var counter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Column {
        Text(text = counter.toString())
        Button(onClick = { counter++ }) {
            Text("Increment")
        }
    }
}
```

---

2. RememberUpdatedState

From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#rememberupdatedstate), we can see that this is specifically used when we are using Side Effects.

Example,

```
@Composable
fun RememberUpdatedStateSample() {
    var afterDelay: () -> Unit by remember {
        mutableStateOf({
            Log.e("Test", "Initial After delay handler")
        })
    }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        delay(1000)
        afterDelay = {
            Log.e("Test", "Updated After delay handler")
        }
    }

    RememberUpdatedStateSampleWithEffect(afterDelay)
}

@Composable
fun RememberUpdatedStateSampleWithEffect(
    afterDelay: () -> Unit,
) {
    val rememberedAfterDelay by rememberUpdatedState(afterDelay)

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        Log.e("Test", "Starting Delay")
        delay(3000)
        Log.e("Test", "Delay Over")
        afterDelay()
    }
}
```

The above code output is,

> Starting Delay
> Delay Over
> Initial After delay handler

From the code, we can see that we are initially passing a lambda to call after the timeout in the SideEffect in `RememberUpdatedStateSampleWithEffect`.

`RememberUpdatedStateSampleWithEffect` has a delay of 3000. So the lambda should have been updated to the updated one, `"Updated After delay handler"` by this time. But, since there is no recomposition when the lambda changes, the output is using the initial lambda and not the updated one.

Changing `afterDelay` in the `LaunchedEffect` inside `RememberUpdatedStateSampleWithEffect` to `rememberedAfterDelay` will give the following output.

> Starting Delay
> Delay Over
> Updated After delay handler

This is useful when we want to use the updated state value without a recomposition happening.

---

3. Difference between using `rememberUpdatedState` and having the changing state as a key for the `SideEffect`.

We can also use the state as a key to get the updated state inside the `SideEffect` like this,

```
@Composable
fun RememberUpdatedStateSampleWithEffect(
    afterDelay: () -> Unit,
) {
    LaunchedEffect(afterDelay) {
        Log.e("Test", "Starting Delay")
        delay(3000)
        Log.e("Test", "Delay Over")
        afterDelay()
    }
}
```

But, if we see the output, we get

> Starting Delay
> Starting Delay
> Delay Over
> Updated After delay handler

We can see that "Starting Delay" is repeated in the output. This is due to the fact that the SideEffect is restarted when the state changes if the state is used as a key.

---