# Usage of remembering a lambda function in rememberUpdatedState()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I see in Compose docs of Google([link](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events#navigation-events)),

There is a **LoginScreen** Compose function and based on an action(for example here, success login), we want then navigate to **HomeScreen** using a lambda function from input of **LoginScreen**,

in Google docs example, they remember the lambda function from input of LoginScreen `rememberUpdatedState()` and when successful login happens, the value of `rememberUpdatedState()` is used to navigate.

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    onUserLogIn: () -> Unit, // Caller navigates to the right screen
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            // ViewModel validation is triggered
            viewModel.login()
        }
    ) {
        Text("Log in")
    }
    // Rest of the UI

    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    val currentOnUserLogIn by rememberUpdatedState(onUserLogIn)
    LaunchedEffect(viewModel, lifecycle)  {
        // Whenever the uiState changes, check if the user is logged in and
        // call the `onUserLogin` event when `lifecycle` is at least STARTED
        snapshotFlow { viewModel.uiState }
            .filter { it.isUserLoggedIn }
            .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
            .collect {
                currentOnUserLogIn()
            }
    }
}
```

I know the usage of `rememberUpdatedState()` for remembering a value and get latest **value**.

but what is usage of this structure to call lambda function ( `onUserLogIn()` ) undirectly from a rememberedUpdateState,

why doesn't it call directly the onUserLogIn lambda function?

Comment: It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70223293/235671) answer explains it. It's about the difference between `remember` and `rememberUpdated` using a lambda as the second example.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of `rememberUpdatedState` - to deliver an updated state into `LaunchedEffect`. If you call `onUserLogIn` directly it will use the initial value from when `LaunchedEffect` was started.